Installing rdkit on AWS glue, can't find setup.py
I am trying to install rdkit on aws glue 4.0 with a Spark job, specifically for getting IDs from an SDF file. I don't have much experience with glue or installing python libraries outside of pycharm or a conda terminal.
Following the documentation provided by AWS:
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html), I've zipped the library and uploaded it to s3, and entered the s3 URI under Job Details > Advanced Properties > Python library path, as well as added a key value pairing of "--additional-python-modules": . Upon running the job, it fails due to being unable to locate a setup.py file:
ERROR: file:///tmp/rdkit.zip does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

Looking at the source code for rdkit, there seems to be multiple setup.py files, so I'm not sure what to do from here. Is there an alternative method I should use for this?

Since rdkit is available on https://pypi.org/, go to glue job details -> Job parameters -> add key '--additional-python-modules' and value 'rdkit'.
